# Is there a way to inspect flash movie elements live in AS2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, section508

I have a major problem with a flash based training course that is rendering extra graphics that are UNSEEN. This is realized when a screen reader is used to run 508 compliance tests on the course. There are various times when it just says 'graphic 13' and I have no way of telling what the object is that is getting this title and becoming available to the screen reader so that I can go disable it. I need a way so that it can be highlighted somehow or I can inspect the entire flash document so that I can see what currently has the name 'graphic 13'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give [X-Ray](http://osflash.org/xray) a try, it works for AS2 and is pretty great for this kind of things.